# Converse theorem of limits inequalities

Tags: real-analysis, limits, analysis, solution-verification, proof-writing

Can the theorem: $f(x)<g(x)  \forall x \in (x_{0}-  \delta ,  x_{0}+  \delta) \Longrightarrow \lim_{x \rightarrow  x_{0} } f(x) \leq \lim_{x \rightarrow  x_{0} } g(x)$

be converse into

$ \lim_{x \rightarrow  x_{0} } f(x)< \lim_{x \rightarrow  x_{0} } g(x) \Longrightarrow f(x)<g(x)  \forall x \in (x_{0}-  \delta ,  x_{0}+  \delta) $
?

By applying the definition of limit I thought that this is true for all $\epsilon < \frac{m-l}{2}$ where $m=lim_{x \rightarrow  x_{0} } g(x)$ and $l=\lim_{x \rightarrow  x_{0} } f(x)$

Comment: What you wrote is true (once you put in the qualifier "there exists a $\delta>0$ such that..."), though it's not really a 'reverse' (the proper term is *converse*), it's a partial converse.

Comment: So is it correct to use the < instead of the $\leq$?   @peek-a

Comment: yes, $<$ is correct.

Comment: If you had used $\le$, in the 2nd theorem, it would be false. For example $f(x) = |x|, g(x) = 0$ with $x_0 = 0$. And if you used $<$ instead of $\le$ in the 1st theorem, it would be false. For example, $f(x) = \begin{cases}0& x\ne 0\\-1&x = 0\end{cases}$ and $g(x) = |x|$. Thus the two theorems you actually have are the best that can be said (other than loosening the condition of the first theorem to $f(x) \le g(x)$).